# RSS link is broken for tagged questions

Tags: bug, status-completed, feed

After searching for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-requests+or+urllib2+or+urlib3 I got rss link https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag?tagnames=python-requests+or+urllib2+or+urlib3&sort=newest which does not point to a valid rss feed.

Comment: Nice catch, Piotr.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fun bug.

For some reason if one of the tags doesn't exist (in your url, that'd be `urlib3`) then we 404 feeds.  Now we'll chug along so long as at least one of the passed tags exist, which seems a lot more sensible.

This fix will go out with the next build.